# Angular Datatable: How to disable immediate row checkbox based on the column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

How to disable row checkbox based on the column data. Have one datatable and have to write one condition, if `firstname="Superman",` need to `disable checkbox of the row.` So not possible to select the checkbox again. I tried with below code and I'm unbale to disable the checkbox. I tried below code,

```
this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
  // setTimeout(() => {
  this.persons = response.data;
  $.each(this.persons, function(key, value) {
    if (value.firstname == "Superman") {
      console.log("inside");
      // $('.checkboxCls').prop('disabled', true);
      $(this)
        .closest("tr")
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
  this.dtTrigger.next();
  // });
});
```

Here is the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-satj31?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for reference. Could you please suggest what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the checkbox from the HTML template side.

```
    <td><input [disabled]="person.firstName === 'Superman'" type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" name="id" [checked]="isChecked" value="{{person.id}}"></td>
```

Edited [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-7d8nmw?file=app/app.component.html) Code